# Javascript date in specified format

Tags: javascript, css

i need to convert date to "2015-03-25T00:00:00.000Z" this format in javascript 
i use the following code

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new Date("2015-03-25");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
  
</body>
</html>
```

i get the result like this 
Wed Mar 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
but i need the following format "2015-03-25T00:00:00.000Z"

Comment: What I Would Suggest Is For All Date Related Stuff You Should Make Use Of Existing Library Called Moment.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new Date("2015-03-25").toISOString();
```

Comment: That may or may not change the time zone of the date. It *should* be treated as UTC, but not all browsers do.

Comment: This is just a parsing operation I guess .

Answer (score 1):

Try this in script

```js
var date = new Date("2015-03-25");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = date.toISOString();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The format you need is called ISO format and fro that You can use [.toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new Date("2015-03-25").toISOString();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```